# MongoDB returning a matching array element in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

is possible to return specific item of array in this example? I'm using mongo version 3 (3.0.4) and mongoDB driver version 1.6.11 in PHP.

I have this object in mongo collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('56e9247287f5204c0a000001'),
    "name": "test name",
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "folder name",
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "item 1",
                    "internalID": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "item 2",
                    "internalID": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "item 3",
                    "internalID": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "item 4",
                    "internalID": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I need to find and return object, with one item where internalID = 2.. The result should be something like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('56e9247287f5204c0a000001'),
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "item 2",
            "internalID": 2
        },
    ]
}
```

The code below not working, returns full object with all items.

```
$collection->find(
    [
        'folders.items.internalID' => 2,
    ],
        [
            'folders' => [
                '$elemMatch' => [
                    'items.internalID' => 2
                ]
            ]
        ]
);
```

Can you help me please? is possible return only one matching item from array in mongodb?

Thank you!

Comment: Please mention your MongoDB and driver version

Comment: I'm using mongo version 3 (3.0.4) and mongoDB driver version 1.6.11 in PHP.

Comment: `$itemMatch` check if a value matches inside array. It doesn't limit your array selection.

Comment: why not just use projection $elemMatch?  You don't need aggregation framework for this.https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Answer (score 0):

I think, that I found the solution:

```
$collection->aggregate(
    array(
        # First match the "document" to reduce the pipeline
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'folders.items.internalID' => 3
            )
        ),

        # Then unwind the array
        array('$unwind' => '$folders'),
        array('$unwind' => '$folders.items'),

        # Match again on the "unwound" elements to filter
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'folders.items.internalID' => 3
            )
        ),

        # Group back to original structure per document
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$_id',
                'items' => array(
                    '$push' => '$folders.items'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$_id',
                'items' => array(
                    '$push' => '$items'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 56e9494087f5204c0a000002
                )

            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => item 3
                                    [internalID] => 3
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Unwind isn't good, but it's workaround.

Comment: ok thank you, and is another better solution (I don't like this code with aggregate, it's too large)? I try nated $elemMatch, but it doesn't works...

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use the aggregation framework.

First of all you need to filter out all those documents that don't match your query criteria using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator. This reduce the amount of documents to process in the next stage.

From there, you need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your documents and use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator new in MongoDB 3.2 to filter out those sub-documents that don't match your criteria. Of course the `$map` operator returns an array of values; here it simply return 2d array.

```
$match = array('$match' => array('folders.items.internalID' => 2));
$project = array(
    '$project' => array('item' => array('$map' => array(
        'input' => '$folders', 
        'as' => 'f', 
        'in' => array('$filter' => array(
            'input' => '$$f.items', 
            'as' => 'af', 
            'cond' => array('$eq' => array('$$af.internalID', 2))
         )), 
    )))
);
```

Which yields this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e96b784839cea8e9a1d098"),
    "item" : [
        [
            {
                "name" : "item 2",
                "internalID" : 2
            }
        ]
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e96bcb4839cea8e9a1d099"),
    "item" : [
        [
            {
                "name" : "item 2",
                "internalID" : 2
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name" : "item 2",
                "internalID" : 2
            }
        ]
    ]
}

$pipeline = array($match, $project);
$out = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
```

As you can see this is not exactly the expected output format but is close enough. You just stop here and process you result client-side. The reason is because to get the exact output format you need to *denormalizate*  the "items" array two times using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator but this operation can be quite expensive if you are dealing with large collections thus result in drop of performance.

```
$unwind = array('$unwind' => '$item');
$group = array('$group' => array(
    '_id' => '$_id', 
    'item' => array('$push' => '$item')
));

$pipeline = array($match, $project, $unwind, $unwind, $group);
$out = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
```

---

Since older version don't support the `$filter` operator you need to use the `$setDifference` operator.

```
$project = array(
    '$project' => array('item' => array('$map' => array(
        'input' => '$folders', 
        'as' => 'f', 
        'in' => array('$setDifference' => array(
            '$map' => array(
                'input' => '$$f.items', 
                'as' => 'af', 
                'in' => array('$cond' => array('$eq' => array('$$af.internalID', 2)), "$$af", false)
            ), 
            array(false)
        ))
    )))
);
```

#### Version 3.2 or newer  shell solution.

```
var match =  { "$match": { "folders.items.intenalID": 2 } };
var project = { "$project": { 
    "item": { 
        "$map": { 
            "input": "$folders", 
                "as": "f", 
                "in": { 
                    "$filter": { 
                        "input": "$$f.items", 
                        "as": "af", 
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$af.internalID", 2 ] }
                    }
                }
            }
     }
}}; 

// optional
var unwind = { "$unwind": "$item" }; 
var group = { 
    "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
            "item": { "$push": "$item" }
     }
};

db.collection.aggregate(match, project, unwind, unwind, group);
```

---

#### Version <= 3.0 solution.

```
var project = { "$project": { 
    "item": { 
        "$map": { 
            "input": "$folders", 
            "as": "f", 
            "in": { 
                "$setDifference": [
                    { "$map": { 
                        "input": "$$f.items",  
                        "as": "af", 
                        "in": { 
                            "$cond": [ 
                                { "$eq": [ "$$af.internalID", 2 ] },
                                "$$af", 
                                false
                             ]
                         }
                     }}, 
                     [false]
                 ]
             }
         }
     }
}};
```